# binary '*' : no global operator found which takes type 'statistician' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload my operators its really just a class that holds arithmetic functions and a sequence of array variables.

But when i am overloading my (*) multiplication operator i get this error:

```
     binary '*' : no global operator found which takes type 'statistician' 
(or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

This happens when my code tries to do: `s = 2*u;`in main.cpp

where s, and u are statistician  classes.

statistician = my class

(statistician.h)

```
class statistician  
{
... other functions & variables...

const statistician statistician::operator*(const statistician &other) const;

..... more overloads...

};
```

Any help would be awesome thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare a namespace scope `operator*`, so that you can also have a *convertible* operand on the *left* hand side that is not of type `statistician`.

```
statistician operator*(const statistician &left, const statistician &right) {
  // ...
}
```

Needless to say that you should remove the in-class one then, and you need a converting constructor to take the `int`.

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly why binary operators like * or + should be non-member.

If you did `s = u * 2`, it would have worked, assuming that you have a non-explicit constructor for `statistician` that takes a single `int` argument.  However, `2 * u` does not work, because 2 is not a `statistician`, and `int` is not a class with a member `operator*`.

For this to work right, you should define a non-member `operator*` and make it a `friend` of `statistician`:

```
statistician operator*(const statistician &left, const statistician &right);
```

You also need to either define other versions of `operator*` that take integers (or whatever other types you wish to be able to "multiply") or define non-explicit constructors for `statistician` to enable implicit conversion.